# cannot find file when accessing via virtual directory in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, virtual-directory, file-not-found

i am accessing files in a virtual folder using classic asp by server objects. here is the code for getting the folder:

```
Set FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim mapPath
mapPath = Server.MapPath("http://development/far/")
Set farFolder = FSO.GetFolder(mapPath)
```

I am getting file not found error when looping through the directory. The files are seen when i put //development/far/ in the browser. I am fairly new to asp so do not know where going wrong.

this is code for when looping through the directory:

```
For Each item in farFolder.Files

Set matches =  re.Execute(item.Name)
if(matches.Count=1) then
Response.Write ("<a target=""_blank""href=""" & item.Path & """>" & item.Name & "</a>  <br>")
End if

Next
```

Comment: Show us the code that loops the directory and produces file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the path part of your URL when calling [Server.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28VS.90%29.aspx):

```
mapPath = Server.MapPath("/far/")
```